# play,pause,resume operations on single button using speechSynthesisis not working

Tags: javascript, html, text-to-speech

I am trying to make the text to speech in the website . I have created the button which performs both the play and pause and resume operation on single button, but I was confused that I cannot hear any voice but it is successfully entering into loops but not able to hear or perform any operation.

```
        var flag = false;
       function listen(){

         console.log("texttospeech")
         var synth = window.speechSynthesis;
      if ('speechSynthesis' in window){
         if(!flag){
          console.log("flag value true")
          flag = true;
           utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(
          document.getElementById("retrievecode").textContent);

          utterance.onend = function(){
          console.log("reached end")
           flag = false;
           };
          synth.speak(utterance);
        }
       if(synth.paused) { /* unpause/resume narration */
         console.log("pauser")
         synth.resume();
       }


   }

   else{
     alert("not supported")
   }
 }
```

Comment: Try commenting out the pitch and rate. Also I assume that's not the complete code because there's an extra } before else.

Comment: If you're using Chrome the code needs to handle the event onvoiceschanged. You could also try substituting the getElementById part for some actual text, just to see if the problem is there.

Comment: @Frazer - How to add voice changed in my code.

Comment: if the retrievecode element is an input field you should use .value instead of .textContent - maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Otherwise try adding speechSynthesis.getVoices(); to the beginning of the script.

Comment: @Keerthi Kothuri have u successfully implemented speech speechSynthesis resume/play/paused?